# Odd issues animating 2 divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

first time asking a question, but this site has answered hundreds for me.

Ok, I am using jquery to animate 2 divs from a button for each. They work, but with a glitch that I cannot figure out. Both divs have a height of 0 in css. If I click the first button, the first div opens. Then click the second button, the first div closes and second opens (as desired). But, if I click the second button again and close the div, then click the first one again, nothing happens until another click. I hope the mumble makes sense. 
Any help solving this glitch would be great, thanks

Here is a jfiddle of it. http://jsfiddle.net/Jptalon/AMu2Z/1/

```
<button id="btnOne">One</button>
<button id="btnTwo">Two</button>
<div id="one">
<p>one text</p>
</div>
<div id="two">
<p>two text</p>
</div>
<script>
var stateone = true;
var statetwo = true;
$(function() {
$("#btnOne").click(function(){
  var x = document.getElementById('two');
  if ( x.style.height != 0){ $("#two").animate({height:"0px" }, "slow"); statetwo = !statetwo;}
   if ( stateone ) {
     $("#one").animate({height:"100px" }, "slow");
   } else {
     $("#one").animate({height:"0px" }, "slow");
   }
   stateone = !stateone;
   });
 });
 $(function() {
 $("#btnTwo").click(function(){
   var y = document.getElementById('one');
   if ( y.style.height != 0){ $("#one").animate({height:"0px" }, "slow"); stateone = !stateone;}
   if ( statetwo ) {
     $("#two").animate({height:"100px" }, "slow");
   } else {
     $("#two").animate({height:"0px" }, "slow");
   }
   statetwo = !statetwo;
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be make such better...

```
<button id="btnOne" class="switch" data-target="#one">One</button>
<button id="btnTwo" class="switch" data-target="#two">Two</button>
<div id="one" class="toggle">
    <p>one text</p>
</div>
<div id="two" class="toggle">
    <p>two text</p>
</div>
```

then

```
.toggle {
    display: none;
}
```

and

```
var $toggles = $('.toggle');
$('.switch').click(function(){
    var $target = $($(this).data('target')).stop(true, true);
    $toggles.not($target).stop(true, true).slideUp();
    $target.slideToggle('slow');
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FSCFU/)

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery [Show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

```
$("#btnOne").click(function () {
    $("#two").hide('slow');
    $("#one").show('slow');

});

$("#btnTwo").click(function () {
   $("#one").hide('slow');
    $("#two").show('slow');

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9nSdp/)